# Dúvidas de principiante sobre criar app no Android

Tags: android

Sou novo no desenvolvimento de app para Android e estou usando o Android Studio para isso, porém gostaria de antecipar algumas dúvidas. São elas:

1. Como faço para no final do projeto publicar no Android?
2. Qual o valor e se o pagamento é anual ou paga-se apenas uma vez?
3. O projeto será destinado a várias empresas. Posso desenvolver app para cada uma dessas empresas dentro da minha conta?
4. Em caso positivo da dúvida 3, terei que pagar algum valor adicional?
5. Quanto tempo demora para a publicação de cada app seja disponibilizada.

Sobre o item 2, consegui a informação [nesse site](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/)

Obrigado

Comment: Antes que alguém com dedo nervoso saia negativando o post, sem ao menos ter conhecimento no assunto, gostaria de informar que minhas dúvidas são relevantes, já que podem sanar dúvidas de muitas pessoas que estão ingressando agora. Os Apps no Android são desenvolvido em Java, porém acredito que, como já tem uma tag Java, poderiam ser mais maleáveis com algumas dúvidas aqui, já que o mundo do Android vai muito além da programação e as dúvidas são amplas, já que dependem de diversos fatores para o sucesso do projeto.

Comment: Não confunda o Android com o Google Play. Fazer aplicativos para Android é grátis e não tem restrições. Colocar no Google Play é outra histo´ria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Você, primeiramente, vai precisar gerar o seu APK assinado e no próprio Android Studio tu faz isso. Tu vai precisar criar uma keystore com algumas informações pessoas para que você possa assinar seu aplicativo. Essa keystore também pode ser criada pela IDE/Android Studio.
2. Para ter uma conta de desenvolvedor e publicar apps na Play Store, você só vai precisar comprar uma pagando **25USD** e só, não precisa de nenhum pagamento adicional ou anual.
3. Você pode publicar quantos aplicativos quiser, para quantas empresas quiser, sem nenhum problema.
4. Não.
5. Geralmente o prazo é de até 24 horas, mas pode ser lançado em até 3 horas.

**Leia mais em**: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/preparing.html?hl=pt-br

Comment: Muito obrigado pelos esclarecimentos itscorey.

Comment: @Fox.11 esse é apenas um breve resumo do processo, mas são informações importantes. No próprio console, quando vc já abrir sua conta, tu terá suas dúvidas esclarecidas completamente! :)